# I need some help with vectors and planes.

Tags: vectors

My question says:

> Consider the vectors $a = i - j + k, b = i + 2j + 4k$ and $c = 2i - 5j - k.$
>
> a) Given that $c = ma + nb$ where $m, n$ are real numbers, find the value of $m$ and $n$
>
> b) Find a unit vector, $u$, normal to both $a$ and $b.$

For $(a)$ I have done this and got $n = -1$ and $m = 3$.

For $(b)$  I got $\frac{1}{\sqrt{118}}\left(-10i-3j+3k\right)$  as my unit vector.

But now I’m faced with

> c) The plane $p_1$ contains the point $A (1, -1, 1)$ and is normal to $b.$ The plane intersects the x, y and z axes at the points $L, M$ and $N$ respectively:
>
> i) Find the Cartesian equation of $p_1$
>
> ii) Write doen the coordinates of $L, M$ and $N$

I’m not sure where to start at this point, can anyone help?

Comment: But $$\vec{c}$$ is given, or i'm missing something?

Comment: Only vector c is given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the equation of plane is $ax+by+cz=d$ then its normal is $<a,b,c>$.
So, $p_1$'s equation is $$1(x-1)+2(y+1)+4(z-1)=0$$ or $$x+2y+4z=3$$
which contains the point $A$.
Converting it to intercept form:
$$\frac x3+\frac y{\frac32}+\frac z{\frac34}=1$$
which gives $L=(3,0,0);M=\Bigl(0,\frac32,0\Bigr);N=\Bigl(0,0,\frac34\Bigr)$.

Comment: Could you please explain how you derived the first equation?

Comment: Taking the dot product of a vector on the plane and its normal gives you $0$. So assume the normal to be standing over the point $A$ and also an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$ on the plane. Now the vector on the plane is simply $<x-1,y+1,z-1>$. Take its dot product with the normal to get a relation between the values of $x,y,z$ which is nothing but the equation of plane